# Firebase email saying my realtime database has insecure rules: Solution

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've stopped to receive emails from Firebase telling me that my realtime database has insecure rules. Here is the beginning of the rules I have set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "aaa":{
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    },
    "bbb":{
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    },
//..... rest of the rules.
  }
}
```

Here "aaa" and "bbb" are the nodes I use in my Firebase realtime databse. So you should mention all of yours.

Is this solution suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Your security rules should *only* allow what your application code does, and nothing more.

So if your code writes directly to `aaa` and/or `bbb` and writes whatever data it wants there, then your rules match that.

But typically your code will write data of a specific structure, in which case you should validate that structure with validation rules.

Also: does your code really need to delete or replace the entire `aaa` and/or `bbb` node? Or does it only need to append new child nodes to it? Because right now, your rules allow any user to take the configuration from your application and then do `firebase.database().ref("aaa").remove()` and wipe whatever is under it. Again: if that matches with what your application does, then the rules match that. But... it seem unlikely.

Comment: My code (client) "aa1" writes to its (sub-) nodes like "aaa/aa1", "aaa/aa1/a2" and so on.

Thanks for the note about "delete".

Answer (score 0):

Always try to include User UID for more security.

```json
"aaa":{
   "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid"
   }
}
```